# PNG, Why is visual studio making me download PNG files?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, file, png

i write  and my page loads it find. When i click on the link instead of having the image show on screen it promps me to download it. Why? How can i make it display in the browser? gif and jpg both display in the browser.

-edit- i am using FireFox 3.5 there is no code that serves it, its just a link and the file exist in my folder. The link is like `http://localhost:1737/a/b/file.png`. IE 8 displays the png w/o making me download. I havent tried with other browsers but surely i click on direct  png link in firefox  on every site mine (in VS) should act the same.

Comment: Try creating a plain .html page with the same .png image and see what happens.  Does this only happen in Visual Studio, or also in the browser?

Comment: You don't say what browser you are using. You might also want to post the code that displays the image.

Answer (score 4):

If you're fetching it with HTTP, then there is a web server serving it. Look at the MIME-type when its returned, is that set correctly?

Telnet to localhost on port 1737 (not sure the syntax on Windows but IIRC try `telnet localhost 1737`) and type:

```
GET /a/b/file.png HTTP/1.0
```

Followed by two returns. Look at the `Content-Type:` field in the header. If it's not something like `image/png` you have a problem serving it. Firefox may have been guessing from the file name.

Comment: Using tamper data in firefox it looks like it is `Content-Type=application/octet-stream` (thats what firefox seems to report). Is there a way to change this without getting dirty in code?

Comment: There's your problem. I have no idea how your web server handles things, but other servers are able to alter the headers based on the file extension. There is sure to be a configuration setting somewhere. If you're using IIS, try taking a look at this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742440.aspx